# Github inspect button code for selenium python module

Tags: python, github, selenium-webdriver

I tried to make a github scrapper but at the last part I am facing an error. And don't worry  the user is not a real person, it is a dummy account made by ryan john from whom I am learning bug bounty hunting from. The code is-

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
#https://github.com/usernam121
scrape = input("What page should I scrape?  ")
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(f"{scrape}")
repo = "https://github.com/usernam121"
res = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "repo")

links = []
flink = []
def going_for_raw(second_page):
    driver.get(second_page)
    raw = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "js-permalink-replaceable-link")
    raw.click()
    html = driver.page_source
    html = f"{html}"
    if "password" in html:
        print(f"password found{second_page}")

    
def loop(next_page):
    global a
    driver.get(next_page)
    res2 = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "js-navigation-open")
    for a in res2:
        pass
      
        
    if "py" in a.text:
        second_page = f"{next_page}/blob/main/{a.text}"
        going_for_raw(second_page)

for i in res:
    links.append(i.text)


for l in links:
    next_page = f"{repo}/{l}"
    flink.append(next_page)
    loop(next_page)

time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

in line 15(raw = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "js-permalink-replaceable-link")) the js-permalink-replaceable-link is giving an error as I have to find a class for the raw button in inspect -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6sbo.png) in this image, but the class is not correct. Can anyone help me to find the correct class for that raw button?
It is showing this error-

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
 element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css 
 selector","selector":".js-permalink-replaceable-link"}
(Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.130); For documentation on this error, 
 please visit: 
  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
    Stacktrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF650622142+3514994]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650240CE2]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6500E76AA]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650131860]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65013197C]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650174EE7]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65015602F]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6501728F6]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650155D93]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650124BDC]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650125C64]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65064E16B+3695259]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6506A6737+4057191]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF65069E4E3+4023827]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6503704F9+689705]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF65024C048]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF650248044]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6502481C9]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF6502388C4]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF8BC707344+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF8BDF226B1+33]
```

I entered this class js-permalink-replaceable-link and I am not getting the correct answer that is all the words in which is after clicking raw button